# Would like webpack to output to separate .css files instead of combining into one

Tags: javascript, reactjs, webpack

I am using `MiniCssExtractPlugin` and also have chunks specified for optimization:

```
splitChunks: {
            cacheGroups: {
                styles: {
                    name: 'styles',
                    test: /\.css$/,
                    chunks: 'all',
                    enforce: true,
                },
            },
        },
```

I believe the chunks causes my two ink CSS to be combined into a styles.[hash].css file after the dev or prod build:

```
import '../../ext/ink-3.1.10/css/ink.min.css';
import '../../ext/ink-3.1.10/css/ink-flex.min.css';
```

**index.tsx**

```
import { render } from 'react-dom';
import React from 'react';
import { Provider } from 'react-redux';
import App from './App';
import '../../ext/ink-3.1.10/css/ink.min.css';
import '../../ext/ink-3.1.10/css/ink-flex.min.css';
import './less/master.less';
import store from './store';
import { BrowserRouter as Router } from 'react-router-dom';

const globalAny: any = global;
globalAny.__base = `${__dirname}/`;


render(
    <Provider store={store}>
        <Router>
            <App />
        </Router>
    </Provider>,

    document.getElementById('app')
);
```

But I don't want the `ink` files to be combined.  But if I take chunks out, then my build no longer includes the two ink css files:

If I leave optimization chunks in, then it's combining those two ink files into a styles.[hash].css and doing so causing weird style issues when I run the site.

I'm new to webpack so don't assume I know completely what I'm doing 100% yet.

How can I change this to output two separate css files for those ink files?

**webpack.config.js**

```
const path = require('path');
const { CleanWebpackPlugin } = require('clean-webpack-plugin');
const TerserJSPlugin = require('terser-webpack-plugin');
const HtmlWebPackPlugin = require('html-webpack-plugin');
const MiniCssExtractPlugin = require('mini-css-extract-plugin');
const OptimizeCSSAssetsPlugin = require('optimize-css-assets-webpack-plugin');
const CopyPlugin = require('copy-webpack-plugin');

const isProduction = process.env.NODE_ENV === 'production';

const html = () =>
    new HtmlWebPackPlugin({
        template: path.resolve(__dirname, 'src/client', 'index.html'),
        filename: 'index.html',
        hash: true,
    });

const copyAllOtherDistFiles = () =>
    new CopyPlugin({
        patterns: [
            { from: 'src/client/assets', to: 'lib/assets' },
            { from: 'package.json', to: './' },
            { from: 'ext/ink-3.1.10/js/ink-all.min.js', to: 'lib/js' },
            { from: 'ext/ink-3.1.10/js/autoload.min.js', to: 'lib/js' },
            { from: 'ext/js/jquery-2.2.3.min.js', to: 'lib/js' },
            { from: 'feed.xml', to: './' },
        ],
    });

module.exports = {
    entry: './src/client/index.tsx',
    output: {
        filename: 'scripts/app.[hash].bundle.js',
        publicPath: '/',
        path: path.resolve(__dirname, 'dist'),
    },
    resolve: {
        extensions: ['.ts', '.tsx', '.js'],
    },
    devtool: 'source-map',
    devServer: {
        open: true,
        writeToDisk: false,
        publicPath: '/',
        compress: true,
        historyApiFallback: {
            index: '/',
        },
        stats: 'errors-only',
        proxy: {
            '/api': {
                target: 'http://localhost:3000',
                secure: false,
                changeOrigin: true,
                logLevel: 'debug',
            },
        },
    },
    optimization: {
        minimizer: [new TerserJSPlugin({}), new OptimizeCSSAssetsPlugin({})],
        splitChunks: {
            cacheGroups: {
                styles: {
                    name: 'styles',
                    test: /\.css$/,
                    chunks: 'all',
                    enforce: true,
                },
            },
        },
    },
    module: {
        rules: [
            {
                test: /\.(js)$/,
                exclude: /node_modules/,
                use: {
                    loader: 'babel-loader',
                },
            },
            {
                test: /\.(tsx|ts)?$/,
                use: 'ts-loader',
                exclude: /node_modules/,
            },
            {
                test: /\.html$/,
                use: [
                    {
                        loader: 'html-loader',
                    },
                ],
            },
            {
                test: /\.less$/,
                use: [MiniCssExtractPlugin.loader, 'css-loader', 'less-loader'],
            },
            {
                test: /\.css$/,
                use: [
                    {
                        loader: MiniCssExtractPlugin.loader,
                        options: {
                            publicPath: '../../',
                        },
                    },
                    'css-loader',
                ],
            },
            {
                test: /\.woff(2)?(\?v=[0-9]\.[0-9]\.[0-9])?$/,
                loader: 'url-loader?limit=10000&mimetype=application/font-woff',
            },
            {
                test: /\.(png|svg|jpg|gif)$/,
                use: ['url-loader'],
            },
        ],
    },
    plugins: isProduction
        ? [
                new CleanWebpackPlugin(),
                copyAllOtherDistFiles(),
                new MiniCssExtractPlugin({
                    filename: 'lib/css/[name].[hash].css',
                }),
                html(),
          ]
        : [
                copyAllOtherDistFiles(),
                new MiniCssExtractPlugin({
                    filename: 'lib/css/[name].[hash].css',
                }),
                html(),
          ],
};
```

**UPDATE:**

Only thing now is that:

1. Also the ink css files to be in the `root` of `lib/css`?  It looks like it's putting it into my `__dirname` and into ext for some reason still instead of next to the `lib\css` next to my `main` css.
2. it seems like I'm getting dups of the ink css created?  It's in a  and in  and in the script looks like it's appended to the app bundle as part of the path?  seems weird
3. I need there to be 2 ink files generated and included in the `index.html`.  It's *combining* those two ink css files (`ink` and ink flex) into **one** `ink` css file.  That causes problems for me.  Looks like the chunking logic isn't creating separate files yet still for the files I included in `index.tsx`?

**webpack.config.js**

```
const path = require('path');
const { CleanWebpackPlugin } = require('clean-webpack-plugin');
const TerserJSPlugin = require('terser-webpack-plugin');
const HtmlWebPackPlugin = require('html-webpack-plugin');
const MiniCssExtractPlugin = require('mini-css-extract-plugin');
const OptimizeCSSAssetsPlugin = require('optimize-css-assets-webpack-plugin');
const CopyPlugin = require('copy-webpack-plugin');

const isProduction = process.env.NODE_ENV === 'production';

const html = () =>
    new HtmlWebPackPlugin({
        template: path.resolve(__dirname, 'src/client', 'index.html'),
        filename: 'index.html',
        hash: true,
    });

const copyAllOtherDistFiles = () =>
    new CopyPlugin({
        patterns: [
            { from: 'src/client/assets', to: 'lib/assets' },
            { from: 'package.json', to: './' },
            { from: 'ext/ink-3.1.10/js/ink-all.min.js', to: 'lib/js' },
            { from: 'ext/ink-3.1.10/js/autoload.min.js', to: 'lib/js' },
            { from: 'ext/js/jquery-2.2.3.min.js', to: 'lib/js' },
            { from: 'feed.xml', to: './' },
        ],
    });

module.exports = {
    entry: './src/client/index.tsx',
    output: {
        filename: 'scripts/app.[hash].bundle.js',
        publicPath: '/',
        path: path.resolve(__dirname, 'dist'),
    },
    resolve: {
        extensions: ['.ts', '.tsx', '.js'],
    },
    devtool: 'source-map',
    devServer: {
        open: true,
        writeToDisk: false,
        publicPath: '/',
        compress: true,
        historyApiFallback: {
            index: '/',
        },
        stats: 'errors-only',
        proxy: {
            '/api': {
                target: 'http://localhost:3000',
                secure: false,
                changeOrigin: true,
                logLevel: 'debug',
            },
        },
    },
    optimization: {
        minimizer: [new TerserJSPlugin({}), new OptimizeCSSAssetsPlugin({})],
        splitChunks: {
            cacheGroups: {
                styles: {
                    name(module) {
                        const match = module.context.match(/[\\/](.*).css/);

                        if (!match) {
                            return false;
                        }

                        const moduleName = match[1];

                        return moduleName;
                    },
                    test: /\.css$/,
                    chunks: 'all',
                    enforce: true,
                },
            },
        },
    },
    module: {
        rules: [
            {
                test: /\.(js)$/,
                exclude: /node_modules/,
                use: {
                    loader: 'babel-loader',
                },
            },
            {
                test: /\.(tsx|ts)?$/,
                use: 'ts-loader',
                exclude: /node_modules/,
            },
            {
                test: /\.html$/,
                use: [
                    {
                        loader: 'html-loader',
                    },
                ],
            },
            {
                test: /\.less$/,
                use: [MiniCssExtractPlugin.loader, 'css-loader', 'less-loader'],
            },
            {
                test: /\.css$/,
                use: [
                    {
                        loader: MiniCssExtractPlugin.loader,
                        options: {
                            publicPath: '../../',
                        },
                    },
                    'css-loader',
                ],
            },
            {
                test: /\.woff(2)?(\?v=[0-9]\.[0-9]\.[0-9])?$/,
                loader: 'url-loader?limit=10000&mimetype=application/font-woff',
            },
            {
                test: /\.(png|svg|jpg|gif)$/,
                use: ['url-loader'],
            },
        ],
    },
    plugins: isProduction
        ? [
                new CleanWebpackPlugin(),
                copyAllOtherDistFiles(),
                new MiniCssExtractPlugin({
                    filename: 'lib/css/[name].[hash].css',
                }),
                html(),
          ]
        : [
                copyAllOtherDistFiles(),
                new MiniCssExtractPlugin({
                    filename: 'lib/css/[name].[hash].css',
                }),
                html(),
          ],
};
```

[image]
[image]

I console.log'd out the matches here to try to troubleshoot:

```
[
  '/Users/xxxxx/code/other/projects/xxxxx/ext/ink-3.1.10/css',
  'Users/xxxxx/code/other/projects/xxxxx/ext/ink-3.1.10',
  index: 0,
  input: '/Users/xxxxx/code/other/projects/xxxxx/ext/ink-3.1.10/css',
  groups: undefined
]
match[1]: /Users/xxxxx/code/other/projects/xxxxx/src/client/ext/ink-3.1.10

[
  '/Users/xxxxx/code/other/projects/xxxxx/ext/ink-3.1.10/css',
  'Users/xxxxx/code/other/projects/xxxxx/ext/ink-3.1.10',
  index: 0,
  input: '/Users/xxxxx/code/other/projects/xxxxx/ext/ink-3.1.10/css',
  groups: undefined
]
match[1]: /Users/xxxxx/code/other/projects/xxxxx/src/client/ext/ink-3.1.10

[
  '/Users/xxxxx/code/other/projects/xxxxx/ext/ink-3.1.10/css',
  'Users/xxxxx/code/other/projects/xxxxx/ext/ink-3.1.10',
  index: 0,
  input: '/Users/xxxxx/code/other/projects/xxxxx/ext/ink-3.1.10/css',
  groups: undefined
]
match[1]: /Users/xxxxx/code/other/projects/xxxxx/src/client/ext/ink-3.1.10

[
  '/Users/xxxxx/code/other/projects/xxxxx/ext/ink-3.1.10/css',
  'Users/xxxxx/code/other/projects/xxxxx/ext/ink-3.1.10',
  index: 0,
  input: '/Users/xxxxx/code/other/projects/xxxxx/ext/ink-3.1.10/css',
  groups: undefined
]
match[1]: /Users/xxxxx/code/other/projects/xxxxx/src/client/ext/ink-3.1.10
```

Answer (score 3):

Please try changing your [cacheGroup name](https://webpack.js.org/plugins/split-chunks-plugin/#splitchunksname) configuration:

```
splitChunks: {
   cacheGroups: {
      styles: {
          name(module) {
             const match = module.context.match(/[\\/](.*).css/);

             if (!match) {
                return false;
             }

             const moduleName = match[1];

             return moduleName;
          },
          test: /\.css$/,
          chunks: 'all',
          enforce: true,
       },
   },
},
```

By defining `name: 'styles'` you told webpack that every module that is imported and match `/\.css$/` regex should be wrap together in **one** chunk named "styles".

the *name* property of *cacheGroup* can also be a function.
This function gets the *module* (object containing lots of data on a give file) and does the following:

1. if false returned: - Doesn't add this module(file) to this chunk group.
2. if a string is returned - push this module(file) to a chunk with this name.

So from one cache group you could generate multiple chunks, depending on what you are returning for each file.

Comment: really appreciate your help and detailed answer. I didn't realize I had to put this much logic into it or how. Check out my update, just a couple things, not quite there just yet